# VBA crash CPU usage (Bloomberg data request)

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba, cpu

I am experiencing crashes in my VBA script and I suspect the cause to be a low level of Free Physical Memory (MB) (Task Manager --> Performance).

My VBA script (in Access) calls Excel objects that retrieve Bloomberg data.

While the excel sheet is loading Bloomberg data, the script executes a check in order to find out if the download of data is completed. For this check I have decided to copy/paste special the data to another sheet and check that none of the cells have a value of "#NA Requesting data..."

If my Free Physical Memory is below 400MB then I get an error message when pasting special the data.

Does anyone have experienced similar issues with a script crashing because it needs more memory and what beside closing applications can be done in order to avoid the situation?

Comment: You're not showing how you're doing it, but "I have decided to copy/paste special the data to another sheet " _Don't do that_. It makes far more sense to search the worksheet for "#NA Requesting data..."

Comment: I have top paste Special since the cells contain formula. `        xlApp.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(3).Cells.Copy
xlApp.Workbooks(1).Worksheets("Check").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying and pasting an entire page can use a lot of system resources. You should always avoid copy and paste if possible. In this circumstance, you can check the values of the source document directly.

Something like the following:

```
Dim foundCells As Object 'Dim as object so you don't need Excel Reference
Set foundCells = xlApp.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(3).Cells.Find(What:="#NA Requesting data...", _
    After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not foundCells Is Nothing Then
    'it's not done yet
Else
    'it's done
End If
```